# Problema com URL do Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, datatable

toda vez que eu vou tentar chamar o metodo do meu controller aparece uma url diferente da que eu estou colocando na url do AJAX, o porque disso ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olhe seu arquivo .htaccess ve se tem alguma regra de reescrita

Comment: Vlw Marcelo, era eu mesmo que estava comendo bronha KKK, um café e um pouco de distração achei o erro

Comment: Tranquilo, hehe :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está usando o método `GET` para enviar dados. Esse método transmite todas as informações pela URL, ou seja, quando está enviando suas informações pela URL, o que pode ser potencialmente perigoso. Em geral usa-se o método `GET` para solicitar dados para seu back end.

Uma requisição usando `GET` vai deixar a url mais ou menos assim

```
http://www.exemplo.com?var1=alguma_coisa&var2=outra_coisa
```

Se você quer transportar seus dados com um nível maior de segurança você deve usar o método `POST`. Caso queira entender melhor sobre esses métodos você pode ler [aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)

Comment: Vlw Phelipe, muito obrigado eu estava fazendo errado mesmo, com o post deu certo e tb estava errando na string da url, Vlw pela ajuda !